# Partial sorting: select at most N elements including for sure the top T elements

Tags: sample-size, quantiles, partial-effect

To whom it may concern.

My "population" with known size P is a landscape and has not more than 4 peaks with about same high. Naturally top elements group locally within the population. I seek the top T elements. Sorting the whole population is easy, but takes to much time.

My question belongs to the topic of partial sorting: Not the whole population shall be sorted, but only at most top N elements, which shall include for sure the top T elements.

To achieve this, I evenly sample the population, sort the sampled set and use a quantile to find / estimate a threshold from the sorted sub-population. Then I split the whole population with the threshold to get (hopefully) at most top N elements, but for sure those top T elements.

1. Can the sufficient sample size S be calculated from P, so that I do not get more than N top elements including for sure those top T elements?
2. The threshold is an estimate. Can the quantile be calculated, so I do for sure do not get more than top N elements?

Which field in statistics belongs this question?

Thanks in advance. Best regards, Stephan

Edit:
Your reflection and further research on the internet convinced me, that my approach is not robust without iterations.
The better approach is a [selection algorithm](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) seeking the [nth element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251781/how-to-find-the-kth-largest-element-in-an-unsorted-array-of-length-n-in-on) in an unordered list.

Comment: I will share my current level as an answer, because as guest I cannot comment. I think I cannot be 100% sure, too. This is the way how I calculate the quantile to access the threshold from the sorted list: uint quantile = N / sampleStepping ; // trunc() uint threshold = d_subKeysIn[ numSamples -1 - quantile ]; In my case: P is 221000, N is desired by me to be less equal 1024, hence N is 1000, sampleStepping is 101 which gives numSamples = 2188 I also was thinking about iterating. But I could also use a larger quantile just from the beginning. But there is this constraint about N ... I tried a

Comment: Please merge your 3(!) accounts (there is information [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)). Then you will be able to edit & comment on your own question & be notified of answers, comments & other activity here.

Comment: The problem with *not* merging accounts is that when the posts you put in place of answers are (necessarily) turned into comments, they get truncated at 500 characters. There's nothing we can do about that.  We can't merge your accounts for you, either: you have to click that button.

Answer (score 2):

Given the description, I don't think you can know anything for *sure* without looking at most of the data. It seems like maybe making a pass through the data is not that expensive but you don't want to do a complete sort. I'd suggest a scheme similar to yours -- something like sampling approximately $P/T$ points; find the max, $m$, of those results (note: you do not need to do a complete sort to do that, just go through the numbers and replace $m$ with a new value whenever it is exceeded); then go through all the data and identify all the points greater than $m$. With a little luck, you'll have at least $T$ of them. If not, go back through using the second largest initial value instead of $m$.

We don't have a probability model for the data you are looking at, so this is really more of an algorithmic, rather than statistical, question. You might find better advice on Stack Overflow?

Comment: (+1) A version of Quicksort, which formalizes the *ad hoc* method described here, is optimal for finding a fixed number $k$ of highest values. It operates in expected $O(k n)$ time for $n$ numbers. A full sort, which takes $O(n\log n)$, is more expensive when $n$ is large and $k$ is small. Heap-based algorithms attain the same asymptotics, too, even in worst-case time.